# SQL Log shipping - Very Slow restore

Tags: sql-server, restore, transaction-log, log-shipping

I have SQL Server 2012 SP4, ten databases and log shipping.

One database 2.7TB

- Ten data files and two log files

Log shipping configuration:

- Transaction log backup job : 3 Min
- Copy job : 1 Min
- Restore job : 1 Min
- Standby Mode, clicked Disconnect users...

A 50MB trn file take at 2 hours restored. The database is being 100% restored and remains. How do i solve this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: How many virtual log files does this database have?

Comment: Changed between 5-30. I shrink log file sometimes.

Comment: If you sometimes shrink the log file it means the log file grows sometimes. Depending on autogrouwth settings for the file that process can take much enough time. Looking at your trn-file's name I can suppose it can be the case because of some nightly scheduled tasks, which make the log file grow. Check it out.

Comment: Yes, there is a shrink job and I disabled. Maybe index job growth the log file. Autogrowth by 1024MB. What should I do to speed up?

Comment: Choose convenient size for your log-file so that it won't grow itself. The only way to speed up the log-file growing process is to place it on as fast as possible drive. So disable your shrink job (done) and look after your log shipping process for some time to make sure it was the mentioned case.

Comment: When you have logshipping in standby mode, the restores can be slow. In order to improve - change the recovery mode to no recovery & then change it back -https://troubleshootingsql.com/2012/09/11/get-your-log-shipping-restore-to-run-faster/

Comment: @DenisRubashkin I did what you told me and I watch the process.

Comment: @Kin I will try to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added sql service account to Perform volume maintenance tasks and disk slowness problem appeared on the server. The storage team replaced the disks with faster disks. Problem is solved.

[image][image]